# ResizeObserver - loop limit exceeded

Tags: google-chrome, aurelia, microsoft-edge, rollbar

About two months ago we started using Rollbar to notify us of various errors in our Web App. Ever since then we have been getting the occasional error:

`ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded`

The thing that confuses me about this is that we are not using `ResizeObserver` and I have investigated the only plugin which I thought could possibly be the culprit, namely:

[Aurelia Resize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-resize)

But it doesn't appear to be using `ResizeObserver` either.

What is also confusing is that these error messages have been occuring since January but `ResizeObserver` support has only recently been added to Chrome 65.

The browser versions that have been giving us this error are:

- Chrome: 63.0.3239 (ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded)
- Chrome: 64.0.3282 (ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded)
- Edge: 14.14393 (SecurityError)
- Edge: 15.15063 (SecurityError)

So I was wondering if this could possibly be a browser bug? Or perhaps an error that actually has nothing to do with `ResizeObserver`?

Comment: Funny how even the docs say `ResizeObserver has a mechanism to avoid infinite callback loops and cyclic dependencies`. Did you update the dependency to element-resize-detector (dependency of aurelia-resize) recently? Seems that one had an update in January..

Comment: As a workaround you could do `window.ResizeObserver = undefined;` at the start of your application to just disable the ResizeObserver. Not the best solution of course, but just reverts it back to what it was when it worked..

Comment: Can you provide a repro of your code, and yes ResizeObserver gives UAs an out (at an unspecified limit) to bail on a loop. The Edge Security Error is going to be completely different as we don't currently support ResizeObserver.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately I won't be able to share the repro. I am discussing the possible solutions put forward by @FredKleuver with my team.

Comment: @FredKleuver it appears that the `aurelia-resize` currently uses and older version of `element-resize-detector` and hasn't been updated.

Comment: @FredKleuver we have decided to park this for now since it seems to be an issue possibly related to dependencies and it is a silent error so we would rather not do anything hacky with it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @IOIIOOIO please consider adding your own response reflecting your decision.

Comment: This error means that ResizeObserver was not able to deliver all observations within a single animation frame. It is benign (your site will not break).

Comment: Ah thanks very much! I think the main concern was that it would cause performance issues. I don't work there anymore but I'll let the guys know.

Comment: @AleksandarTotic It is still strange that we were getting this error from a browser that doesn't support it, and when our app didn't appear to be using it.

Comment: it's a real PITA if you are trying to use `onerror`.  To make matters worse, safari will prevent the message from showing up so you can't even filter it out

Comment: @AleksandarTotic thank you for the information here! I do have a question though: like with the question author, my hybrid app does not use ResizeObserver anywhere (even searching my entire computer, the only instance of ResizeObserver is a random Steam file). I'm concerned that this is indicative of another issue on the app; what would be the mechanism for this error happening when the ResizeObserver is never used?

Comment: >  what would be the mechanism for this error happening when the ResizeObserver is never used?        This error will never happen if RO is not used. Where is the usage coming from? I see 2 options. A) An extension, or B) RO is used internally by Chrome in some tags (video). B) should not happen, and is a bug. If you have a reproducible case you can share, please file a bug on crbug.com.

Comment: @AlexanderTaran we were using a video that was getting a ResizeObserver attached by Chrome; thank you for the help here! I really appreciate it

Comment: In case you want to explicitly ignore it, you must also do the same thing with Firefox's version of this which is `ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications.` (including the period)

Answer (score 424, accepted):

You can safely ignore this error.

One of the specification authors wrote in a comment to your question but it is not an answer and it is not clear in the comment that the answer is really the most important one in this thread, and the one that made me comfortable to ignore it in our Sentry logs.

> ﻿This error means that ResizeObserver was not able to deliver all observations within a single animation frame. It is benign (your site will not break). – [Aleksandar Totic](https://github.com/WICG/ResizeObserver/commits?author=atotic) Apr 15 at 3:14

There are also some [related issues](https://github.com/WICG/ResizeObserver/issues/38) to this in the specification repository.

Comment: Also see [Error "ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded" Firing When Video Controls Exist](https://crbug.com/809574).

Comment: We had this issue in coming from `@microsoft/applicationinsights-web` which does our client error logging. So we just ignore this error by setting up an error event handler prior to applicationInsights and call `stopImmediatePropagation` and `preventDefault`

Comment: @JohnnyFun any thoughts on how to do that on safari?  No matter what I only get "script error." when this event happens

Comment: I'm not sure it's always sensible/safe to ignore this error. It can indicate a performance problem, for example: https://jsbin.com/cadafaduwu/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output. The resize observer callback triggers the element to resize again, thus creating a loop. When this happens, it's usually a mistake—you don't want to trigger another resize from a resize observer callback.

Comment: Also, there's a good description of why this error happens here: https://webkit.org/blog/9997/resizeobserver-in-webkit/#:~:text=observation.-,How%20Observations%20are%20Delivered,ResizeObserver,-strictly. (In Safari the error message is slightly different but the logic still applies.)

Comment: In case it helps anyone understand why they are seeing this error, I created a repository with a bunch of different reduced test cases where you might run into this error: https://github.com/OliverJAsh/resize-observer-loop-tests

Comment: Related ticket, including the error message for Firefox and a little workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64257593/472804

Comment: @JohnnyFun Facing the same issue. @microsoft/applicationinsights-web is logging "ResizeObserver - loop limit exceeded". Could you please post code snippet that you wrote to suppress this error from @microsoft/applicationinsights-web logs.

Comment: Something like this: `window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', e => { if (/resizeobserver/.test(e?.message || e || '').toString()) e.preventDefault(); e.stopImmediatePropagation() })`

Answer (score 103):

It's an old question but it still might be helpful to someone. You can avoid this error by wrapping the callback in `requestAnimationFrame`. 
For example:

```js
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
   // We wrap it in requestAnimationFrame to avoid this error - ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded
   window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
     if (!Array.isArray(entries) || !entries.length) {
       return;
     }
     // your code
   });
});
```

Comment: is the condition needed? "!Array.isArray(entries) || !entries.length"

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: How did you know to do this...?

Comment: @ADJenks from a response above: "This error means that ResizeObserver was not able to deliver all observations within a single animation frame". By wrapping it in requestAnimationFrame you can limit the executions to a single frame

Comment: You may not want to do this. " you can limit the executions to a single frame"  A more accurate explanation is that you're actually pushing the layout change onto the macrotask queue. This is unfortunately an important distinction, because RO normally would run inbetween layout and paint. This is important because it lets you make layout changes without "jank" or "flickering"

You can find a great example of that here: https://github.com/petyosi/react-virtuoso/issues/269

That doesn't mean that you cannot use this solution -- but if you are using RO for sync updates, reconsider.

Comment: Nice approach, but to make it potentially more beneficial - you are required to call `requestAnimationFrame` only once. Any further calls could process the array directly without wrapping. I'm not sure though if it gives any particular perf benefits.

Comment: Note that this trick means your resizes will always be lagging one frame behind, which may not always be what you want.

Answer (score 64):

If you're using Cypress and this issue bumps in, you can safely ignore it in Cypress with the following code in support/index.js or commands.ts

```js
const resizeObserverLoopErrRe = /^[^(ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded)]/
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err) => {
    /* returning false here prevents Cypress from failing the test */
    if (resizeObserverLoopErrRe.test(err.message)) {
        return false
    }
})
```

You can follow the discussion about it [here](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/2233).
As Cypress maintainer themselves proposed this solution, so I believe it'd be safe to do so.

Comment: Your regex doesn't quite do what you'd expect it to do. The square brackets enclose a character class, which the ^ inside it negates so in reality you're ignoring any error that starts with any of the characters included in the sentence. If you want to use a regex, the negative lookahead is what you're looking for: `return /^(?!ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded)/.test(err.message)` should be fine. Though `err.message.startsWith('ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded')` might be easier anyhow.

Comment: I would even go as far as to state a regular expression is unnecessary for that -- you can just look for the string `"ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded"` inside the error message, plain and simple.

Comment: I can confirm that `if (err.message.includes("ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded"))` works as well as the regex.

Answer (score 11):

We had this same issue. We found that a chrome extension was the culprit. Specifically, the loom chrome extension was causing the error (or some interaction of our code with loom extension). When we disabled the extension, our app worked.

I would recommend disabling certain extensions/addons to see if one of them might be contributing to the error.

Comment: Or just check in incognito mode. Most people are likely to have either none, or far fewer extensions enabled in incognito.

Comment: +1 worked for me. Im my case, it was "Avira" chrome extension causing the error "ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded"

Answer (score 10):

For Mocha users:

The snippet below overrides the window.onerror hook mocha installs and turns the errors into a warning.
https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/667e9a21c10649185e92b319006cea5eb8d61f31/browser-entry.js#L74

```js
// ignore ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded
// this is ok in several scenarios according to 
// https://github.com/WICG/resize-observer/issues/38
before(() => {
  // called before any tests are run
  const e = window.onerror;
  window.onerror = function(err) {
    if(err === 'ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded') {
      console.warn('Ignored: ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded');
      return false;
    } else {
      return e(...arguments);
    }
  }
});
```

not sure there is a better way..

Comment: This worked for me, except that I had to `return true` in the `if`, to prevent the firing of the default event handler ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#window.onerror)).

Comment: There _is_ a better way to _do the same thing_ -- without `window.onerror` "acrobatics". Don't use `onerror` -- use `addEventListener` with `"error"` as event type, and `stopPropagation` to stop propagation of the event as needed. Alternatively, add the event listener on the object you suspect of actually firing the error event, and stop propagation there. This has been covered in detail in answers to related questions.

Comment: Where is `arguments` coming from?

Comment: @JoeTidee https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 9):

The error might be worth investigating. It can indicate a problem in your code that can be fixed.

In our case an observed resize of an element triggered a change on the page, which caused a resize of the first element again, which again triggered a change on the page, which again caused a resize of the first element, … You know how this ends.

Essentially we created an infinite loop that could not be fitted into a single animation frame, obviously. We broke it by holding up the change on the page using `setTimeout()` (although this is not perfect since it may cause some flickering to the users).

So every time `ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded` emerges in our Sentry now, we look at it as a useful hint and try to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This was our case, we have image observer and observer tried send request to the server to get a new image derivative but server responded with 404 and Opera/Chrome adds default icon to indicate a broken image. This icon trigered a new observer call because the size of image changed and we again reset image by setting image.src that causes infinite process.
Here some more details https://dgo.to/easy_responsive_images/3285476
The solution in our case was checking observed image size to detect if this image is not default broken image icon.

Comment: Would it be possible to call this.unobserve() before you do your changes in side the ResizeObserver, and then when you are done turn this.observe() to restart? I am running in to this problem too and there is quite some work done before the new final size is determent. Couldn't get this to work though :(

Answer (score 6):

add debounce like

new ResizeObserver(_.debounce(entries => {}, 200);

fixed this error for me

Comment: this works but i some cases will cause janky behavior, for example when animating the closing of a panel. setting the wait to `1` seems to have resolved the error for me while keeping the animation smooth.

Answer (score 4):

One line solution for Cypress. Edit the file support/commands.js with:

```js
Cypress.on(
  'uncaught:exception',
  (err) => !err.message.includes('ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue "ResizeObserver - loop limit exceeded" was triggered because of `window.addEventListener("resize"` and React's `React.useState`.

In details, I was working on the hook called `useWindowResize` where the use case was like this `const [windowWidth, windowHeight] = useWindowResize();`.

The code reacts on the *windowWidth/windowHeight* change via the *useEffect*.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    ViewportService.dynamicDimensionControlledBy(
        "height",
        { windowWidth, windowHeight },
        widgetModalRef.current,
        { bottom: chartTitleHeight },
        false,
        ({ h }) => setWidgetHeight(h),
    );
}, [windowWidth, windowHeight, widgetModalRef, chartTitleHeight]);
```

So any browser window resize caused that issue.

I've found that many similar issues caused because of the connection *old-javascript-world* (DOM manipulation, browser's events) and the *new-javascript-world* (React) may be solved by the `setTimeout`, but I would to avoid it and call it anti-pattern when possible.

So my fix is to wrap the setter method into the *setTimeout* function.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    ViewportService.dynamicDimensionControlledBy(
        "height",
        { windowWidth, windowHeight },
        widgetModalRef.current,
        { bottom: chartTitleHeight },
        false,
        ({ h }) => setTimeout(() => setWidgetHeight(h), 0),
    );
}, [windowWidth, windowHeight, widgetModalRef, chartTitleHeight]);
```

Answer (score 2):

We also had that issue with [Monaco Editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor) because it is using `ResizeObserver` internally.

To fix it, we patched the original API by doing:

```js
class CalmResizeObserver extends ResizeObserver {
  constructor(callback: ResizeObserverCallback) {
    super((entries, observer) => {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        callback(entries, observer);
      });
    });
  }
}

win.ResizeObserver = CalmResizeObserver;
```

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS. The error is harmless. Just ignore it. This "fix" breaks synchronous rendering. https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5488#issuecomment-812279513

> Many folks simply ignore it via RAF / setTimeout by queueing a microtask / microtask but this defeats the purpose -- since you don't get synchronous rendering! For example, see petyosi/react-virtuoso@5475a10

Answer (score 1):

https://github1s.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/third_party/blink/renderer/core/resize_observer/resize_observer_controller.cc#L44-L45
https://github1s.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/third_party/blink/renderer/core/frame/local_frame_view.cc#L2211-L2212

After looking at the source code, it seems in my case the issue surfaced when the NotifyResizeObservers function was called, and there were no registered observers.

The GatherObservations function will return a min_depth of 4096, in case there are no observers, and in that case, we will get the "ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded" error.

The way I resolved it is to have an observer living throughout the lifecycle of the page.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was only interested in changes to an element's width. But changing the element's height during a ResizeObserver event caused a "ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded" error.

To suppress the error, I stopped observing prior to changing the element's size, and started observing again after rendering was complete. Essentially:

```
const observer = new ResizeObserver(function (entries) {
    observer.unobserve(element);
    // ...manipulate the element...
    setTimeout(function () {
        observer.observe(element);
    }, 0);
});
```

The complete solution is here: https://gist.github.com/diachedelic/b026fdd168c8af8cd8ac5cb914e7b3cc.

Comment: Why do you setTimeout(()=>{}, 0) ?

Comment: I just copied your example and put some extra text in the element that is .unobserved(element) and than .observe(element) again. It keeps recalling itself even when I set the timeout to 1000..

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you studied the complete solution I linked to?

Comment: I am testing using cypress in Firefox and Electron. I studied the example again. I added the checks if the width is defined and not equal to the current width. Now the function seems to be called only initially and not on resizes.. I posted a question about it...maybe you would have time to look at it? thank you in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/q/77304207/1735311

Answer (score 1):

Reactjs

Fix Error: ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('error', e => {enter code here
      if (e.message === 'ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded' || e.message === 'Script error.') {
        const resizeObserverErrDiv = document.getElementById(
          'webpack-dev-server-client-overlay-div'
        )
        const resizeObserverErr = document.getElementById(
          'webpack-dev-server-client-overlay'
        )
        if (resizeObserverErr) {
          resizeObserverErr.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        }
        if (resizeObserverErrDiv) {
          resizeObserverErrDiv.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        }
      }
    })
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this in React for our error logger setup.

The Observer error propagates to the `window.onerror` error handler, so by storing the original `window.onerror` in a ref, you can then replace it with a custom method that doesn't throw for this particular error. Other errors are allowed to propagate as normal.

Make sure you reconnect the original `onerror` in the `useEffect` cleanup.

```
const defaultOnErrorFn = useRef(window.onerror);

useEffect(() => {
  window.onerror = (...args) => {
    if (args[0] === 'ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded') {
      return true;
    } else {
      defaultOnErrorFn.current && defaultOnErrorFn.current(...args);
    }
  };
  return () => {
    window.onerror = defaultOnErrorFn.current;
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with cypress tests not being able to run.
I found that instead of handling the exception the proper way was to edit the tsconfig.json in a way to target the new es6 version like so:

```js
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
    "target": "es5", --> old
    "target": "es6", --> new
    "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress"],
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Cypress/Jest/Mocha, you can avoid this error with a polyfill:

```
npm install resize-observer-polyfill --save-dev
```

Add this to the test:

```
global.ResizeObserver = require('resize-observer-polyfill');
```