# "ResizeObserver - loop limit exceeded" | API is never used

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am running a hybrid PhoneGap app (for a several years, running Cordova Android 6.1.2, more recently 9.0); for years, our #1 javascript error by a *significant* margin has been

```
ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded
```

***However***, the key distinction for my issue compared to the many other reports found on Google of this error is is that there are 0 instances of ResizeObserver being used anywhere in my code. Searching my entire computer, the only instance of ResizeObserver showing up *anywhere* is a random Steam file. Looking at my app while it's running, setting `window.ResizeObserver = undefined` doesn't break/do anything and `document.resizeObservers` (per the W3C documentation) returns nothing.

I have seen this post, which seems to be the canonical one for this error: [ResizeObserver - loop limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384120/resizeobserver-loop-limit-exceeded) . The answer of "This error means that ResizeObserver was not able to deliver all observations within a single animation frame. It is benign (your site will not break)." would be sufficient for me if I was actually using ResizeObserver. Since I am not using it, I am concerned that this error showing up is indicative of something larger going wrong.

There is no discernible pattern from our users' Chrome version/locale/time zone/Android version/etc/etc, unfortunately.

I've researched this API extensively and have found nothing that would indicate to my issue; either why there would be some sort of phantom ResizeObserver running and/or why that error would show up in an app that doesn't use that API.

Any help here (even just a vague direction to look at) would be very much appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=809574

Even the browser's Shadow DOM may be using this API, and cause this error to fire.
You can still safely ignore it.

Comment: This was it! Chrome was automatically attaching an observer to a video tag. For folks' future reference: the occurrence of ResizeObserver does appear to be associated with taxing the CPU/GPU. Consistent with Kaiido, there's no actual problem and it can be ignored, but if you're really trying to squeeze out every last percent out of your performance, it could be a signal to look at.

Comment: Note that a comment near the bottom of the Chromium issue also gives a workaround for the issue. (the observer is still attached, but the width of the video controls element is locked using css, avoiding the loop-limit-exceeded error/notification)