# CSS resize property: Resize all elements simultaneously?

Tags: css

Given a page which has say 5 textboxes, resizable in height with the css `resize` property.

If the user resizes one of them, all 5 textboxes should resize simultaneously.

How to achive that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Resize Textboxes Simultaneously</title>
  <style>
    textarea {
      resize: vertical;
      height: 16px;
      width: 18%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea>
    Non eram nescius, Brute, cum, quae summis ingeniis exquisitaque doctrina philosophi Graeco sermone tractavissent, ea Latinis litteris mandaremus, fore ut hic noster labor in varias reprehensiones incurreret. nam quibusdam, et iis quidem non admodum indoctis, totum hoc displicet philosophari. quidam autem non tam id reprehendunt, si remissius agatur, sed tantum studium tamque multam operam ponendam in eo non arbitrantur. erunt etiam, et ii quidem eruditi Graecis litteris, contemnentes Latinas, qui se dicant in Graecis legendis operam malle consumere. postremo aliquos futuros suspicor, qui me ad alias litteras vocent, genus hoc scribendi, etsi sit elegans, personae tamen et dignitatis esse negent.
  </textarea>
  <textarea>
    Contra quos omnis dicendum breviter existimo. Quamquam philosophiae quidem vituperatoribus satis responsum est eo libro, quo a nobis philosophia defensa et collaudata est, cum esset accusata et vituperata ab Hortensio. qui liber cum et tibi probatus videretur et iis, quos ego posse iudicare arbitrarer, plura suscepi veritus ne movere hominum studia viderer, retinere non posse. Qui autem, si maxime hoc placeat, moderatius tamen id volunt fieri, difficilem quandam temperantiam postulant in eo, quod semel admissum coerceri reprimique non potest, ut propemodum iustioribus utamur illis, qui omnino avocent a philosophia, quam his, qui rebus infinitis modum constituant in reque eo meliore, quo maior sit, mediocritatem desiderent.
  </textarea>
  <textarea>
    Sive enim ad sapientiam perveniri potest, non paranda nobis solum ea, sed fruenda etiam [sapientia] est; sive hoc difficile est, tamen nec modus est ullus investigandi veri, nisi inveneris, et quaerendi defatigatio turpis est, cum id, quod quaeritur, sit pulcherrimum. etenim si delectamur, cum scribimus, quis est tam invidus, qui ab eo nos abducat? sin laboramus, quis est, qui alienae modum statuat industriae? nam ut Terentianus Chremes non inhumanus, qui novum vicinum non vult 'fodere aut arare aut aliquid ferre denique' -- non enim illum ab industria, sed ab inliberali labore deterret --, sic isti curiosi, quos offendit noster minime nobis iniucundus labor.
  </textarea>
  <textarea>
    Iis igitur est difficilius satis facere, qui se Latina scripta dicunt contemnere. in quibus hoc primum est in quo admirer, cur in gravissimis rebus non delectet eos sermo patrius, cum idem fabellas Latinas ad verbum e Graecis expressas non inviti legant. quis enim tam inimicus paene nomini Romano est, qui Ennii Medeam aut Antiopam Pacuvii spernat aut reiciat, quod se isdem Euripidis fabulis delectari dicat, Latinas litteras oderit? Synephebos ego, inquit, potius Caecilii aut Andriam Terentii quam utramque Menandri legam?
  </textarea>
  <textarea>
    A quibus tantum dissentio, ut, cum Sophocles vel optime scripserit Electram, tamen male conversam Atilii mihi legendam putem, de quo Lucilius: 'ferreum scriptorem', verum, opinor, scriptorem tamen, ut legendus sit. rudem enim esse omnino in nostris poetis aut inertissimae segnitiae est aut fastidii delicatissimi. mihi quidem nulli satis eruditi videntur, quibus nostra ignota sunt. an 'Utinam ne in nemore . . .' nihilo minus legimus quam hoc idem Graecum, quae autem de bene beateque vivendo a Platone disputata sunt, haec explicari non placebit Latine?
  </textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which 5 textboxes? In your question are no textboxes, just 1 textarea. Without context isn't possible to find a solution.

Comment: @pavel Sorry for that, I've updated the question now with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't find a way to do this in pure CSS so put here a JS/CSS solution in case it is of help.

Basically we use the ResizeObserver method to catch a resize on a textarea  and update the heights of the other textareas. We don't let more than one area's resize be coped with at a time else there can be some unwanted looping.

```js
const areas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
let curResizer = 0;
let curTimeout = 0;

for (let i=0; i<areas.length; i++) {
  new ResizeObserver(resizeAll).observe(areas[i]);
}

function resizeAll(curObserved) {

  if  (curResizer == 0 ) { curResizer = curObserved[0].target; }
  if ( curResizer == curObserved[0].target) { 
    for (let i=0; i<areas.length; i++) {
    //does the system always get the height in curResizer set up before the resize observed code is run 
      if (areas[i] != curResizer) {areas[i].style.height = curResizer.style.height;
      }
    }
  }
  if (curTimeout != 0) {clearTimeout(curTimeout);}
  curtimeout = setTimeout(clearCur,1000);// bit of a hack ? could use unobserve?
}
function clearCur() { curResizer = 0; }
```

```css
textarea {
  resize: vertical;
   height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
```

There is a ResizeObserver loop error shown on some systems but according to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384120/resizeobserver-loop-limit-exceeded` they are benign and just mean it couldn't keep up.

Comment: @A Haworth That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!