# ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded - stop exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, sentry

Have been hitting the `ResizeObserver - loop limit exceeded` error on my webapp.
From [ResizeObserver - loop limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384120/resizeobserver-loop-limit-exceeded), I know that the error is harmless. But it still logs into my error/exception tracking on Sentry.

I am currently on a plan that only gives me 5k events per month. Due to very high usage of the webapp (several thousand users), the above **ResizeObserver** error accounts for about 2.5-3k of those errors usually. Which causes my 5k total events per month to deplete before the whole month is complete. Thus, keeping me out of loop for the exceptions towards the latter half of the month.

There isn't really a stack-trace available to point out where exactly the exception is coming from. (refer attached image)
[image]

**Does anybody know how to handle the exception `ResizeObserver - loop limit exceeded` ?**

PS - My frontend stack includes BackboneJS with a lot of use of jQuery. (and a bunch of other libraries)

Comment: https://forum.sentry.io/t/resizeobserver-loop-limit-exceeded/8402/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was in the same situation, only Safari browser reports errors, just ignore it.

```js
ignoreErrors: [
  // Ignore Safari browser errors
  'ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded'
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Not throwing only on Safari (Chrome too), but can be safely ignored.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).