# "flex: 1 1 0%" with a canvas child that adapts its size is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

The following example creates a header, a canvas, and a footer. The canvas is told to fill the space between header and footer. The following happens:

- Expand the window: The canvas grows
- Shrink the window: Scrollbars appear, but I want the canvas to shrink

Why is the canvas not shrinking and how can I make it shrink?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

function paint() {
  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillText(canvas.height, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
}

paint();
new ResizeObserver(paint).observe(canvas);
```

```css
.main {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.canvas {
  flex: 1 0 0%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas"></canvas>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is not working correctly?

Comment: @LearningMathematics sorry, thought it was implicit. Added the question now...

Comment: There is a loop limit error, you'll find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384120/resizeobserver-loop-limit-exceeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `canvas` height to 0 and `flex-grow` to 1 seems to achieve what you want.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");



function paint() {
  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillText(canvas.height, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
}

paint();
new ResizeObserver(paint).observe(canvas);
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

canvas {
  height: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas"></canvas>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: btw. adding "overflow: hidden" to canvas also works

Comment: @user3612643 but will it shrink correctly?