# Error: ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded

Tags: javascript, dom, automation, cypress, resize-observer

I'm trying to automate a login through google in some application, and i received this error message: (uncaught exception)Error: ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded
Error
The following error originated from your application code, not from Cypress.

> ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your application it will automatically fail the current test.

This behavior is configurable, and you can choose to turn this off by listening to the uncaught:exception event.

this is my code :

```
describe('empty spec', () => {
  it('login multi domain ', () => {
    cy.visit('/login');
    cy.get('form > .flex').click({force:true});


    cy.origin(`https://accounts.google.com`, ()=>{
        cy.get("#identifierId").type("user");
        cy.get(".VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ").click({force:true});
        cy.get(`#password`).type("pass");
        cy.get(".VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ").click({force:true});
    })
  })
})
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You can see from the message that it's an error in the app. This section of the documentation gives some recommendation [To turn off all uncaught exception handling](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#To-turn-off-all-uncaught-exception-handling) of how to by-pass the error for testing purposes.

This would be the conservative way to do it

```js
  Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    if (err.message.includes('ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded')) {
      // ignore the error
      return false   
    }
  })
```

With the `if()` statement, you are only ignoring that particular error.

According to this question [ResizeObserver - loop limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50387233/16997707) the message is benign and can be ignored.

Comment: Where i need to write it inside the test ?

Comment: At the top or place in `/cypress/support/e2e.js` for all specs.

Comment: Still not working, the problem is when i type the password

Comment: I tried to cy.log in the function that you provided and nothing were printed to the screen, which means that the function is not gtting excecuted at all

Comment: That's a pity, did you read the documentation? It works for other people, you could raise an issue with Cypress - but unfortunately they will want a reproducible example.

Comment: Yes i read the doc . i tried to put this function at the top of the test and in command.js. I tried to debug and see if this function exceecute and its not

Comment: This happens when the type function in the input text is excecute

Comment: Does anyone know why this function isn't getting excecuted ?