# How to stop 'ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded' error from appearing in React app

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, material-ui, eslint, resize-observer

Recently, a new error started showing in my React application:

`ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded`

Seems that the general consensus is that the error is benign and [there is nothing to worry about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50387233/7214345).

However, I am not sure how to ignore it or to get it to stop showing up when I am testing my program via `npm start`.

The screen that appears looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to suppress this particular errror on this page or otherwise so I don't have to dismiss it every time?

The error comes from the [MUI Masonry component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-masonry/) i use but my understanding is it can come from many dependencies.

Here is the code in which I use it incase that helps in supressing this error.

```
import Masonry from '@mui/lab/Masonry';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { BsFillPlusSquareFill as AddButton } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import { LoadingIndicator } from '../LoadingIndicator';
import { BackButton } from './BackButton';
import styles from './SheskaList.module.css';

export const SheskaListContent = (props: { loading: boolean, cards: ReactNode[] }) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return (
        <Box className={styles.gridContainer}>
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200' />
            <div className={styles.pageTitleContainer}>
                <h1 className={styles.pageTitle}> Your Sheska List </h1>
                <AddButton size={'3em'} className={styles.addCardButton} onClick={() => {navigate('/newitem')}} />
            </div>
            <Masonry columns={{lg: 2, xs: 1}} spacing={3} id={styles.grid}>
                {
                    props.loading
                    ?
                    <LoadingIndicator />
                    :
                    props.cards[0] as NonNullable<ReactNode>
                }
                <BackButton key='back-button' location='/dashboard' text='Return to Home' />
                {
                    !props.loading
                    &&
                    props.cards.slice(1)
                }
            </Masonry>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

I have tried updating my dependencies and seeing if anybody else has had this issue on github but I could not find anything. Please let me know if there are any solutions i can try, I saw that it is possible to edit ESLINT configs but I really want to avoid ejecting my create-react-app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same issue but with a virtualized list from `react-virtuoso` after updating webpack version to 5.x.x (https://github.com/petyosi/react-virtuoso/issues/254). based on the answer from Hai Nguyen Le (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76107850/3328233) I created a simpler version of it to only catch the ResizeObserver error:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('error', e => {
        if (e.message === 'ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded') {
            const resizeObserverErrDiv = document.getElementById(
                'webpack-dev-server-client-overlay-div'
            );
            const resizeObserverErr = document.getElementById(
                'webpack-dev-server-client-overlay'
            );
            if (resizeObserverErr) {
                resizeObserverErr.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
            }
            if (resizeObserverErrDiv) {
                resizeObserverErrDiv.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
            }
        }
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: using the setAttribute('style', 'display: none') method didn't work for me. Instead, remove() method for the element worked

Comment: It worked for me, I replaced the condition because I got a different message "ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications"; so --> `if (e.message.startsWith('ResizeObserver loop')) {`

Answer (score 9):

You can configure webpack not to show overlay on this error. To do this you can add in config inside field: "client", which is inside field "devServer", this:

```js
    overlay: {
      runtimeErrors: (error) => {
        if (error.message === 'ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded') {
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      },
    },
```

Here's the docs about it: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#overlay .

Comment: This got me closer to my answer. I had to set `devServer.client.overlay` to `false`.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue, it ended up to be due to the first element inside the Masonry component having 100% width, once I removed that (actually made it responsive under XS to be 100% - where it had no issue..) issue stopped..

Comment: Same issue here, could you provide an example of your solution please ?

Comment: @NicoSan <Box xs={{width: '100%'}}></Box> inside the Masonary component would do this..

Comment: I don't know how much time this comment has just saved me but I'm sure it's a lot, thank you

Comment: Same issue with react-reflex lib, can't have a 100% width child in there directly. Thanks man, saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

In your React App, push this code:

```
    useBeforeRender(() => {
    window.addEventListener("error", (e) => {
      if (e) {
        const resizeObserverErrDiv = document.getElementById(
          "webpack-dev-server-client-overlay-div",
        );
        const resizeObserverErr = document.getElementById(
          "webpack-dev-server-client-overlay",
        );
        if (resizeObserverErr)
          resizeObserverErr.className = "hide-resize-observer";
        if (resizeObserverErrDiv)
          resizeObserverErrDiv.className = "hide-resize-observer";
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

and  create hooks: useBeforeRender

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useBeforeRender = (callback: any, deps: any) => {
  const [isRun, setIsRun] = useState(false);

  if (!isRun) {
    callback();
    setIsRun(true);
  }

  useEffect(() => () => setIsRun(false), deps);
};
```

use this in .scss or .css file:

```
.hide-resize-observer {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running AG Grid (as I am)...

This was a bug in v29.X that was logged as
AG-8567 Grid shows error ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded

You can see this in the changelog:
https://ag-grid.com/changelog/?searchQuery=8567

This issue is now fixed in AG Grid v30 and later.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because in calling function , was calling the endpoint before state update.

Fix : After updating the state , calling the endpoint

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because I was misusing the `onFirstDataRenderered` of `ag-grid`. This error may occur if you use onFirstDataRendered to call the `sizeColumnsToFit` method. Instead, you should use `onGridReady`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
       // prevent React's listener from firing
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      // prevent the browser's console error message
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Add this code to your index file and see result !

Comment: that would stop every error, which is not what they asked for