# How to stop React Overlay from appearing on a specific error

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, preventdefault, resize-observer

I am trying to stop `ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded` error from showing up on my development enviornment of my react application.

[image]

The error is [benign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384120/resizeobserver-loop-limit-exceeded/50387233#50387233)

How can I get React to stop showing this in my application when in development? It does not show up in production builds.

I have tried adding this code to the top-level of my application at `index.tsx`:

```
window.addEventListener('error', event => {

    if (event.message.includes('ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log(event.message)
    }
});
```

The `console.log(event.message)` is being executed and the error name that it outputs is correct. But the react overlay error still appears.

Comment: Did you try `stopImmediatePropagation` per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384120/resizeobserver-loop-limit-exceeded/50387233#comment111116078_50387233

Comment: Yep, still same issue. :( @SterlingArcher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using webpack, you can configure it not to show overlay on this error. To do this you can add in field: "client", which is inside field "devServer", this config:

```
      overlay: {
    runtimeErrors: (error) => {
      if (error.message === "ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded") {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
```

Here's the docs about it: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#overlay .

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it,  I resorted to manually downgrading all my dependencies, still not sure which one is but if you are dealing with this that is something you can try.

I went through each dependency and rolled it back until the error stopped, it was an incredibly arduous process as I had to run `npm install` for each and find the old version number on npm's website.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Ashar Rahman : Are you using @mui/lab package ? I got the same thing using Masonry from @mui/lab

Comment: @NicoSan YES! I @mui/lab was one of the dependencies that I rolled back meaning that it must have been that package. Glad to have confirmed it.

Comment: @Ashar Rahman : For information, I have openned an [issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/36909). Hope we can found a solution fastly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used an old version of React and the following syntax in the index.js file:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading="null" persistor={persistor}>
       <App />
      </PersistGate>
</Provider>
</BrowserRouter>,
document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Solution:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading="null" persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
);
```