# JavaScript ResizeObserver keeps on calling itself after unobserving the element

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, resize-observer

In a component of a Vue3 app I am building I want to observe an HTML Element and when it resizes I want to trigger some computations that resize the Element a couple of times. Once the final value is known I want to turn the observing back on.

I am using ResizeObserver for this and [copied this solution from this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75818644/1735311).

```js
<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

  const a = ref(null)
  let resizeObserver = null

  onMounted (() => {
    const element = document.getElementById('a-span')
    a.value.textContent = 'resize'

    resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {

      resizeObserver.disconnect(element)

      a.value.textContent = a.value.textContent.concat('- some text- ')

      setTimeout(() => {
        resizeObserver.observe(element)
        }, 1000)
    })

    resizeObserver.observe(element)
  })
</script>

<template>
  <span id="a-span" ref="a">no text</span>
</template>
```

No matter how many Milliseconds I make it wait, it will call itself over-and-over again.

I have the feeling that .observe(element) does an initial call to the `(entries) => {` so I tried putting an `if (runCode) {` around the ResizeObserver logic and set `runCode = false` at the beginning and back to `true` at the end. This also doesn't work...

What is the best way to observe an HTML element for size and when it changes preform a 1001 changes to that element. Then after it is done again check if the size of the element changes?

Comment: The logic looks good, all I can see is that you are attempting to disconnect a target element which is not how it works. `resizeObserver.disconnect()` to disconnect all target elements or `resizeObserve.unobserve(element)` to unobserve a specific target element. I would also say to disconnect or unobserve at the end of your observe method. Otherwise the destruction could prevent the method from completing and your setTimeout function from running

Comment: @SpencerMay what do you mean with "to disconnect or unobserve at the end of your observe method"?

Comment: https://github.com/WICG/resize-observer/issues/65

Comment: @diachedelic so I must remove the current <span> and put a new <span> in place? do I understand it correctly then?

Comment: No, ResizeObserver ignores `element` if it has inline display. Try using a <div> instead.

Comment: @diachedelic if you write it up in a anwser I will give you the credits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@diachedelic pointed out: "ResizeObserver ignores element if it has inline display. Try using a `<div>` instead."

The anwser by @Ale_blianco has two errors in it and I can't edit it. So here is the correct code:

```js
<template>
  <div id="a-div" ref="a">no text</div> <!-- this was a span should be a div -->
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const a = ref(null);
let resizeObserver = null;
let width;

onMounted(() => {
  const element = document.getElementById('a-div');
  a.value.textContent = 'resize';

  resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(function on_resize(entries) {
    if (entries[0].contentRect.width !== width && width !== undefined) {
      resizeObserver.disconnect();

      a.value.textContent = a.value.textContent.concat('- some text - ');

      setTimeout(() => {
        resizeObserver.observe(element);
      }, 0);     
    }
    width = entries[0].contentRect.width; //<-- this needs to be outside the if(){...}
  });

  resizeObserver.observe(element);
});
</script>
```

This is correct working code.